# How can i use 'set_password' in custom non-admin model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, string-hashing

I want to use hashing field set_password from User model in `django.contrib.auth.models` and I'm currently using a custom User model for that.

I'm getting the following error: `Attribute error: 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password'`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    profile_picture = 
     models.ImageField(upload_to="user_data/profile_picture", blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**views.py**

```
...
from .models import User

...
    def post(self, request):
        # Data is here
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # create object of form
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            # cleaned/normalised data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            # convert plain password into hashed
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            return HttpResponse('Done here.')
            ...
```

**forms.py** (just used a widget in forms.py)

```
from .models import User
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

Comment: Could you add which form you use?

Comment: The model will be more useful. Is it a custom User model? Does it inherit from one of the abstract user classes?

Comment: yes it is a custom User model in which i want to use hashing field from contrib.auth.models User

Comment: Please add the form and the model

Comment: i'm just asking for is... "how to use set_password" out of default models.

Comment: Line I said, you need your User model to inherit from AbstractBaseUser.

Comment: can you provide ma snippet for that? just an idea. and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really easy fix. Just change your models.py file like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_data/profile_picture", blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

That way, your user model will inherit all of the `AbstractBaseUser` methods, including `set_password`.

Look at this [full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) from the documentation for extra information.

Comment: I override the AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager. It is as my own preference. But The above will work well. Thanks Gal Silberman

Comment: I like the Abstraction and extending to the AbstractBaseUser, it works best.